# Does unintentionally disconnecting count as a loss?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

My internet shut off during a comp game with my friends.  When I was able to restore it, it was too late.  I was on a four game win streak; does this count as a loss?

Comment: Hey Tyler, welcome to the site.  Try asking your second question as a separate post.  That way you'll get more focused answers.  =]

Comment: check your own stats and see if you got a loss.

Answer (score 3):

Not only does it count as a loss, you also get a ban for disconnecting while playing Competitive somewhere between 30 Minutes and 7 Days, unless you are able to reconnect to the game within 5 minutes. The length of the ban depends on your previous record and will get longer over time.

I can only recommend not to play Competitive if your internet connection is not stable enough to hold one full game of a maximum amount of 90-100 minutes.

There is no way the game can tell if a disconnect is intentional or not, so there are measures in place to punish notorious leavers.

Comment: doesn't it count as 2 losses as a penalty for leaving?

Comment: @Neffer_23 Do you have a source on that?