# I lagged out and rejoined my comp game will i have any penalty?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

So yesterday I was playing on mirage and all the sudden auto disconnect. So when I got disconnected I rejoined the comp game will I have any sort of penalty for leaving but not abandoning? The reason this isn't a duplicate is because he didn't rejoin the game on time but I did. So therefor since I left the game but rejoined do I get a penalty.

Comment: [Related?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/202399/does-unintentionally-disconnecting-count-as-a-loss)

Comment: kinda but the thing is he didn't reconnect in time and i did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you're able to reconnect, then the only loss is the round you weren't there and your team was handicapped - no penalty for you.
2. If you weren't able to reconnect, that means that either you abandoned or 3 minutes passed and you didn't connect - this is recorded as a lost game for you (regardless if your team won or not) and you have a temporary ban (from 30 minutes to 7 days, depending on whether you were banned recently or not)

Anywhere else, but competitive you can leave freely and there are no penalties.

Comment: so since I didn't abandon the match  it doesn't count as anything except for the team losing a round or 2 correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct @captaincj2005

Comment: In some cases (probably not yours) its even better to kick very bad players, get a bot to stay in base, have your top-frager be more aggressive and then play as the bot too.